# Angular2 - subscribe to changes in service data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to get a chart component to re-draw when a new line is added by another component.
I use a service to connect the two and thought the BehaviourSubject would be the way to go, but apparently I didn't understand something correctly yet.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class LineService
{
    private allLines:BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

    constructor()
    {}

    public getAllLines(): Observable<Array<any>>
    {
        return this.allLines.asObservable();
    }

    public addLine(line: any)
    {
        this.allLines.getValue().push(line);
        // this.allLines.next(line); <- this was wrong!
        this.allLines.next(this.allLines.getValue()); // <- emit the entire array
    }
}
```

The chart component then subscribes to the service

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.lineService.getAllLines().subscribe(l => { 
         this.lines = l;
         this.reDrawChart(); // <- need to manually trigger redraw, ngOnChanges is not called by the subscription
      });
}
```

I thought this would be enough to trigger an `ngOnChanges` in the chart component once `addLine` is called by the other component, but that is not the case.
Obviously I didn't understand something correctly and would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: update question with getValue function. or give me name of your array or list of object.

Comment: I don't understand. `getValue()` is part of the BehaviorSubject to access the actual data array, the name of my array is `allLines` (wrapped in the BehaviorSubject).

Comment: `.subscribe(l => {this.lines = l;console.log(this.lines)})` check do you get anything in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working correctly. I guess you expectation is something else.

I think (I may be wrong) to update your chart (I think you need whole array rather than single value).

here I try to replicate your issue.

- **http://plnkr.co/edit/ACiKrXsVQErxBkE18IzW?p=preview**

check **yellow** and **pink** section. **Yellow** section receives **single value**, while **pink** section receives **whole array**.

I think (again I may be wrong)

```
public addLine(line: any)
    {
        this.allLines.getValue().push(line);
        //this.allLines.next(line);
        this.allLines.next(this.allLines.getValue());  //<----I believe this.allLines.getValue() returns array elements.
    }
```

If it doesn't give what you want, I'm ready to delete this answer.

Comment: You are right, this was one problem. If I now trigger the redraw manually it all works. I somehow expected `ngOnChanges` to be triggered automatically by the subscription which is obviously not the case. Thx!